# HTML Table in Wordpress, Making Involuntary Gaps

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I've have a html table which I am pasting into WP, but when I preview it, it shows space between the various cells, even though the cell spacing and padding is 0.

It works fine outside of WP, but inside Wordpress, it messes things up.

Any ideas?

```
 <table id="optin" width="573" height="296" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/cont_01.gif" width="35" height="80" ></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/cont_02.gif" width="500" height="80" ></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/cont_03.gif" width="38" height="80" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/cont_04.gif" width="35" height="280" ></td>
    <td valign="top">


        <table width="96%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="47%"><img style="float:left; vertical-align:top" src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/text.gif"  /></td>
            <td width="53%" rowspan="2"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/67/1134442067.js"></script></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img style="float:left; vertical-align:bottom" src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/card.png"  /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        </td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/cont_06.gif" width="38" height="280" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/cont_07.gif" width="35" height="48" ></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/cont_08.gif" width="500" height="48" ></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.flexkomsystem.com/images/optin/cont_09.gif" width="38" height="48" ></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you've not reset the cellpadding/cellspacing on all your tables, also might be worth checking the styles set in wordpress to see if they have any unwanted defaults.

```
table { 
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

it also might be worth replacing `width="x"` with a style.

Comment: How do I reset cellpadding and spacing?
I've already check the css stylesheet for any table properties, but dont see any

Comment: you should be able to place the code i've posted above into your stylesheet. might be worth checking to see if your default wordpress stylesheet is doing anything with the table selector as well.

Comment: I have checked the style sheet and I see nothing with the word table on there.

I pasted your code on my WP html editor and it got rid of some of the gaps, but not all.

Any ideas?